# Will there be tablet support?

Tags: system-installation, touchscreen, elementary-project, tablet

Are there any plans for tablet support? 
You can add swipe, long press, right mouse button, scrolling, modify the keyboard...

Comment: Have installed freya to my Lenovo X200t, in the login i can open a screen keyboard. But after login, onboard crash and i am searching for a solution to have an onscreen keyboard.
The X200t is wacom based, so all stick functions work well at the box.

Comment: I would also like to see "tablet mode" supported as I recently installed Elementary OS Loki on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 11e 3rd Gen. While the touch screen of my laptop is supported, the operating system still recognizes keyboard and touch pad input while in "tablet mode". An on-screen keyboard would be helpful for us who have these types of convertible notebook computers. Also, It would be nice to see swipe to scroll through the application menu (and other system menus where applicable). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

elementary OS is focused on the PC and tablets are not officialy supported, but it is possible to install elementary OS on them http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EuzuoFt15YM

Answer (score 0):

you may need this G640S graphics tablet https://www.xp-pen.com/goods/show/id/371.html  ,

XP-Pen Star G640S Graphics Drawing Pen Tablet with Battery-free Stylus and 6 Hot Keys , it works well with system linux/windows/Mac

Answer (score 0):

now 5 years later, any update ?
just installed elementary 6.0 on my laptop.
the rotation bug is fixed ! great.
when i convert laptop to tablet, the keyboard still remains active.
a shortcut to disable keyboard would be sufficient.